How to login to db2u pod using rsh and execute db2 commands via shell script?
I have a script check.sh, which log in to db2u pod(oc rsh db2u-pod /bin/bash), then how to execute below such commands in a script, now my scripts ends after log in, cannot execute below commands
db2 connect to 
how to programmatically run those?
now my scripts ends after log in, cannot execute below commands
db2 connect to 
how to programmatically run those?

Do you mean how to execute a script that is stored on the Db2 machine after logging in wiith "oc rsh"?
